ZNS Connect integration
Gm,
I have a question.
We have a few mints on different chains: Scroll and Taiko. We need to insert the treasure into Safe.
Here are the links:

Scroll Token: https://scrollscan.com/token/0xb00910bac7da44c0d440798809dbf8d51fdbb635
Taiko Token: https://taikoscan.io/token/0xfb2cd41a8aec89efbb19575c6c48d872ce97a0a5

Can you help connect us with the team? We have a few questions to ask.
Thank you!
